# How to choose a template when creating a Web App Bot?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to create a bot using the Azure Portal, trying to follow some tutorials from the documentation. Specifically, these:

- Microsoft Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0
- Azure 4 Everyone https://youtu.be/-FHc_lZ6jJY

When I got to the Azure portal and try to create a Web App Bot however, I am unable to choose a template. It seems to assume I want to create a QnA Bot, which is not the case. I've been doing tutorials and research for a few days; I'm pretty sure I recall this was not the case as of yesterday.

Did something get updated? Is using the Visual Studio template my only option now? I was hoping to use VS Code for the development once I downloaded the basic bot template.

**Edit**: I include a screenshot here of the blade I get when clicking "Create" on Web App Bot in the Marketplace.

URL: https://portal.azure.com/?Microsoft_Azure_BotService_subscriptionId=a2096f22-5a26-42bf-962a-aa232ff81cfe&Microsoft_Azure_BotService_qnaHostName=qna-testbot-001.azurewebsites.net&Microsoft_Azure_BotService_qnaKbId=87f53208-171f-4323-9905-3257bef5cdf3&Microsoft_Azure_BotService_csResourceGroupName=rg-bot-dev-001&Microsoft_Azure_BotService_csAccountName=qna-testbot-001&botsvc.rp=true#create/Microsoft.BotServiceSdkGalleryPackage

[image: No template selection is available.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some folks might just be getting the wrong link in the Azure Portal for some reason. [This one should work](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.BotServiceSdkGalleryPackage).

---

You should be able to choose from:

- C# or Node, then
- Echo Bot or Basic Bot

In the Azure Portal, click "Create a resource"

[image]

In the search bar, type "Web App Bot" and click Create

[image]

Then select the appropriate bot under Bot template

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can start with any of [the samples](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-samples), which offers a much much wider selection of starting points.

Comment: I don't have that option, though... I've been following those steps and any permutation I can think of, but I don't see those options. I'll include a screenshot in my original post to better illustrate my point. Thanks!

Comment: @Kross Interesting. Are you accessing the portal via [portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com)? Is the URL `https://ms.portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.BotServiceSdkGalleryPackage`?

Comment: Huh, the URL you provided works, and I can choose the template as expected. This was working yesterday, too. Since this morning, clicking the "Create" button leads me to the blade that illustrated above.

I placed the link text I get when clicking "Create" in my original post, since it's too long for this section.

Comment: @Kross Weird. Not sure why that's happening. I get the same thing if I visit your link. Maybe worth clearing cache/cookies. Glad my other link works. I'll edit it into the answer.